# Changing deployment project on TFS2010 build

Tags: iis, tfs, tfsbuild

The solution I'm building contains a whole lot of projects. One of them, Web, is the front end web site, and is being built and deployed to the QA server by default when a QA build is run. I have another project, called Service (and an associated Service.TestHarness), which I'd like to deploy to the same server as part of the same build. Where in the build's settings, or in the BuildProcessTemplate, can I configure this?

I've tried creating a deployment package via Visual Studio and importing this manually in IIS on the QA server, but got the error "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified" which I haven't been able to resolve either.

```
Current build settings:
DeploymentApplicationPath = QA server's address
DeploymentComputer = QA server's name
DeploymentPackageSource = Web.zip
PerformDeploy = true
PerformDeploymentBackup = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's four ways you can do this:

1) pass everything as parameters to msbuild using the Team Build Process settings This is the least flexible and doesn't work well if you have multiple deployment projects as you currently have

2) create a custom target and a set of conditions in the project files and let msbuild handle the deployment, don't configure anything in the Build Definition itself (other than maybe setting a property on the msbuild command line arguments to enable a specific deployment)

3) use the Solution Configuration to create a specific solution configuration for each deployment you want to do and when specifying the solution/configuration to build in the build definition, enter your own custom configuration

4) let Team Build handle the build and use something like [TFS Deployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/) or Powershell to handle the actual deployment of the packages.